# Installing fresh react app with dockerfile

Tags: node.js, reactjs, docker, npm

I'm trying to run a fresh installation of React using a Dockerfile.

```
FROM node:12.14-alpine

RUN mkdir /app
WORKDIR /app

RUN npm install -g nodemon \
    npx create-react-app .

COPY package.json package.json
RUN npm install --silent

COPY . .

CMD [ "node", "start" ]
```

My root folder is empty so no package.json file exists etc. When I run `docker-compose up --build` I get the following error which indicates that's failing on `npx create-react-app .`

```
Step 5/9 : RUN npm install -g nodemon     npx create-react-app .
 ---> Running in c4878af5f94d
npm ERR! code ENOLOCAL
npm ERR! Could not install from "" as it does not contain a package.json file.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2020-02-18T12_55_14_899Z-debug.log
ERROR: Service 'react' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c npm install -g nodemon     npx create-react-app .' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong? I'm not having node or npm installed natively so all needs t run through docker

Comment: I’d suggest building your application _first_ — with a local Node — and only then bringing out Docker.  Running `create-react-app` and creating a new empty application as the single thing packaged in your image doesn’t seem like it will be that useful.

Comment: @DavidMaze is this not possible to be done using docker? I'd prefer to have my local os clean

Comment: or if there's another way to install react?

Answer (score 1):

You need to delete the . at the end of the RUN :

```
RUN npm install -g nodemon \
    npx \
    create-react-app
```

Comment: I tried your code but this still throws an error `ERROR: Service 'react' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c npm install -g nodemon     npx     create-react-app' returned a non-zero code: 239` Also when you run the `create-react-app` isn't this suppose to create a package.json file for me?

Comment: I passed this error adding --force to the npm command :
npm install --force -g ...

Answer (score 0):

You forgot "&&" at the beginning line 7

```
FROM node:12.14-alpine

RUN mkdir /app
WORKDIR /app

RUN npm install -g nodemon \
    && npx create-react-app .

COPY package.json package.json
RUN npm install --silent

...

CMD [ "node", "start" ]
```